# Oracle - runtime and show data based on inserted year ( not duplicate )

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sqlfiddle

FacilityTable

```
FACILITYNO    FACILITYNAME
'FACNO01'        Toilet
'FACNO02'       Staff Office
'FACNO03'     Principle Office
'FACNO04'       Science Lab
'FACNO05'       Math Lab
'FACNO06'       Computer Lab
'FACNO07'        Biology Lab
'FACNO08'       Chemical Lab
```

BookingTable

```
FACILITYNO  bookingID       userID     Timebooked  
'FACNO01'       1             0003    10-May-2016       
'FACNO04'       2             0001    10-May-2018    
'FACNO05'       3             0001    10-Apr-2017
'FACNO01'       4             0001    10-Apr-2017
'FACNO02'       5             0003    10-Jan-2011
'FACNO04'       6             0006    10-Apr-2018
'FACNO06'       7             0003    10-Apr-2016
'FACNO07'       8             0006    10-Apr-2015
'FACNO08'       9             0001    10-Apr-2017
```

Expected Result (after insert &n -> Year 2016)

```
FACILITYNAME  count_times  MONTH
Toilet          1            5
Computer Lab    1            4
```

---

On this code I , when runtime is used (&n) and I entered 2016' it will show the expected table that I have provided above.

Below is my code ( but ended up error/duplicate , appearing the data even is not the year I have inserted (2016) )

```
SELECT f.FACILITYNAME,COUNT(*) AS count_times, EXTRACT (MONTH FROM b.Timebooked ) AS MONTHS
FROM BookingTable b
JOIN FacilityTable f ON b.FACILITYNO = f.FACILITYNO
WHERE TO_CHAR(b.Timebooked , 'YYYY') = &n
GROUP BY (EXTRACT (MONTH FROM b.Timebooked )),f.FACILITYNAME
ORDER BY (EXTRACT (MONTH FROM b.Timebooked ))
```

Comment: "When **runtime** is used"??  Do you mean "substitution variable"?

Comment: @mathguy the & is used where to allow user to enter the data , in my case which is enter year .

Comment: Please copy and paste the error message exactly as it appeared when you ran the query. Your explanation "ended up error/duplicate" doesn't make any sense; what "duplicate"? Did it end up in an error, or did it work but produced the wrong answer?

Comment: I know how the & is used. That is not called "runtime" (which has a completely different meaning); what you have there is called a SUBSTITUTION VARIABLE.

Comment: @mathguy , sorry for the lack of understanding regarding on the keyword, the result that appeared is that will show everything (facilityname and the count )that existing in the BookingTable , for now I unable to access to my computer which i will be online in the next 5-6 hour , and i will update the result

Comment: what exactly is the error you are getting

Comment: @DanielMarcus example, if i enter 1980 , the result will still show the data that existing on my database

Comment: And i am not sure weather is that my query have some error that caused this problem , or i used the wrong method

Comment: Your query is good. You have some issue with your substitution.

Comment: As in substitution is on fk and pk ?

Comment: Be cautious! There are always people on this site that want to get out the full error message text from you.

Comment: I did not take any advantage on this site , just want to know that is my query have some error , and i need to know. I tried all my best to solved it before I post my issue on this site. Sorry if you felt that I taking this site as a advantage to solve my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No problem seems with proper formatting (using `quotes` & `to_date` whenever needed) :

```
create table FacilityTable (FACILITYNO varchar2(30), FACILITYNAME varchar2(30));
insert into FacilityTable values('FACNO01','Toilet');
insert into FacilityTable values('FACNO02','Staff Office');
insert into FacilityTable values('FACNO03','Principle Office');
insert into FacilityTable values('FACNO04', 'Science Lab');
insert into FacilityTable values('FACNO05','Math Lab');
insert into FacilityTable values('FACNO06','Computer Lab');
insert into FacilityTable values('FACNO07','Biology Lab');
insert into FacilityTable values('FACNO08','Chemical Lab');


create table BookingTable (FACILITYNO varchar2(30),bookingID int, userID varchar2(30), Timebooked date);
insert into BookingTable values('FACNO01',1,'0003',to_date('10-May-2016','dd-Mon-yyyy'));       
insert into BookingTable values('FACNO04',2,'0001',to_date('10-May-2018','dd-Mon-yyyy'));    
insert into BookingTable values('FACNO05',3,'0001',to_date('10-Apr-2017','dd-Mon-yyyy'));
insert into BookingTable values('FACNO01',4,'0001',to_date('10-Apr-2017','dd-Mon-yyyy'));
insert into BookingTable values('FACNO02',5,'0003',to_date('10-Jan-2011','dd-Mon-yyyy'));
insert into BookingTable values('FACNO04',6,'0006',to_date('10-Apr-2018','dd-Mon-yyyy'));
insert into BookingTable values('FACNO06',7,'0003',to_date('10-Apr-2016','dd-Mon-yyyy'));
insert into BookingTable values('FACNO07',8,'0006',to_date('10-Apr-2015','dd-Mon-yyyy'));
insert into BookingTable values('FACNO08',9,'0001',to_date('10-Apr-2017','dd-Mon-yyyy'));

SELECT f.FACILITYNAME,COUNT(*) AS count_times, EXTRACT (MONTH FROM b.Timebooked ) AS MONTHS
FROM BookingTable b
JOIN FacilityTable f ON b.FACILITYNO = f.FACILITYNO
WHERE TO_CHAR(b.Timebooked , 'YYYY') = &n
GROUP BY (EXTRACT (MONTH FROM b.Timebooked )),f.FACILITYNAME
ORDER BY (EXTRACT (MONTH FROM b.Timebooked ));

FACILITYNAME    COUNT_TIMES MONTHS
Computer Lab           1    4
Toilet                 1    5
```

[Demo(2016 directly substituted for &n)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/13a6a/2)

Comment: Thank you. it solved. seem like my date entered wrong format