# Specific Data Query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, operators

Link for previous thread- LINKED
[Oracle - runtime and show data based on inserted year ( not duplicate )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49561045/oracle-runtime-and-show-data-based-on-inserted-year-not-duplicate)

Summary

> Based on the link above, I have continued to code more specfic result
>   that I want, which i have met some problem during the code which is
>   using "WHERE" statement for showing specfic data after using
>   subsitution variable(&)

Based on the working code that provided by Mr.Barboros, I wanted to add some query to show ONLY some location , example,

I have query 2016 , which should only show 2 result

```
FACILITYNAME COUNT_TIMES    MONTHS
Science Lab     1             4
Science Lab     1             5
```

> But it always show extra Location which is Biology even in 2016 there
>   is no Biology inserted to the DB. 
>   - If i added more location with "OR" , it will still continue show the result , below is the code for my query.

```
SELECT f.FACILITYNAME,COUNT(*) AS count_times, EXTRACT (MONTH FROM b.Timebooked ) AS MONTHS
FROM BookingTable b
JOIN FacilityTable f ON b.FACILITYNO = f.FACILITYNO
WHERE TO_CHAR(b.Timebooked , 'YYYY') = 2018
AND f.FACILITYNAME = 'Toilet' OR f.FACILITYNAME = 'Science Lab' OR  f.FACILITYNAME = 'Biology Lab'
GROUP BY (EXTRACT (MONTH FROM b.Timebooked )),f.FACILITYNAME
ORDER BY (EXTRACT (MONTH FROM b.Timebooked ));
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/13a6a/9

> The result that I want is, when i entered any year , only show
>   Toilet,Science Lab Biology Lab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to add '()' around the group of 'OR' conditions.  Without the brackets, `AND` will take precedence over `OR`. Refer to [SQL Logic Operator Precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241142/sql-logic-operator-precedence-and-and-or).

Try this:

```
SELECT f.FACILITYNAME,COUNT(*) AS count_times, EXTRACT (MONTH FROM b.Timebooked ) AS MONTHS
FROM BookingTable b
JOIN FacilityTable f ON b.FACILITYNO = f.FACILITYNO
WHERE TO_CHAR(b.Timebooked , 'YYYY') = 2018
AND (f.FACILITYNAME = 'Toilet' OR f.FACILITYNAME = 'Science Lab' OR  f.FACILITYNAME = 'Biology Lab')
GROUP BY (EXTRACT (MONTH FROM b.Timebooked )),f.FACILITYNAME
ORDER BY (EXTRACT (MONTH FROM b.Timebooked ));
```

Without the brackets, your query is actually doing this (which is incorrect):

```
SELECT f.FACILITYNAME,COUNT(*) AS count_times, EXTRACT (MONTH FROM b.Timebooked ) AS MONTHS
FROM BookingTable b
JOIN FacilityTable f ON b.FACILITYNO = f.FACILITYNO
WHERE ( TO_CHAR(b.Timebooked , 'YYYY') = 2018
AND  f.FACILITYNAME = 'Toilet') OR f.FACILITYNAME = 'Science Lab' OR  f.FACILITYNAME = 'Biology Lab' 
GROUP BY (EXTRACT (MONTH FROM b.Timebooked )),f.FACILITYNAME
ORDER BY (EXTRACT (MONTH FROM b.Timebooked ));
```

Comment: i see , that's why there is a duplicate, thanks kc2018 ! but i do have another question ( not related to this question ) , i have online check that if i want to show April instead of '4' , how should i do it ? i tried to change 'YYYY' to 'YEAR' it not working

Comment: oracle , myOra (SQL EDITOR)

Comment: thanks ! will try to edit my code , thanks for the help @kc2018

Comment: @whalesboy you are welcome.  Here is a link on converting a date to month name: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497456/get-month-name-from-date-in-oracle